# Function not recognizing libraries

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have the simplest of questions, but this has never happened to me and can't find an answer.
I have the following piece of code:

```
import datalab as dl
import pandas as pd
```

Where datalab is a script I wrote, and between other things, it contains this very simple function:

```
def fecha(vartime, df=df):
    return pd.to_datetime(df[vartiempo])
```

So, when I try to run the function, like this:

```
dl.fecha('time_obtained')
```

I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

Even though I'm quite sure I imported pandas as pd. Is there something I'm missing when importing user functions? I'm a bit perplexed.
Any help is appreciated
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each Python module has its own global namespace. So if you want to use the `pd` name in the `datalab` module, you need to import it there as well, usually at the top of the script, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
…
def fecha(vartime, df=df):
    …
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I feel a bit dumb now, it was actually very simple